# When converting to PDF, how to keep "radio button" square instead of circle?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, webforms

Background:
I am new to learning HTML and frontend development. Currently, I am working on creating an HTML form for users to input their information. First, I utilized an online free tool to convert an existing PDF form into HTML format. After the conversion process, I received several files, including .woff, .svg, .css, and HTML files. These files contained the necessary components for the form. One observation I made is that the user selection boxes are represented by files with the ".svg" extension. To tailor the form to our business requirements, I began customizing the HTML file.

Example:
This is a segment of the original PDF that needs to be replicated on the web form:
[Original PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxK1M.png)

Below is a section of my form in the frontend view. Both question 8 and 9 require single selections from the user. The functionality works well, allowing users to enter and save data. When they check one of the boxes, it automatically unchecks the previously checked box, as it's set up with "radio buttons" for single selection:
[Web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDGN0.png)

This is the html code for the above content mentioned, I'll use question 8 as an example:

```
<!-- Section 8 Starts-->
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:53.5943em; left:3em;">
                        <span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="font-weight:bold;">8</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:53.5943em; left:3.42em;">
                        <span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="font-weight:bold;">.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:53.5943em; left:4.5em;">
                        <span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="font-weight:bold; word-spacing:0.0016em;">Business Ownership Ethnicity: &nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:54.5543em; left:5.835em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_23" style="word-spacing:0.0009em;">African American or Black (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="African American or Black"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:55.5143em; left:5.835em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_37" style="word-spacing:-0.0013em;">American Indian or Alaskan Native (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="American Indian or Alaskan Native"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:56.4693em; left:5.835em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_29" style="word-spacing:-0.0057em;">Asian (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Asian"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:54.5543em; left:22.3817em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_26" style="word-spacing:0.0009em;">Hispanic or Latino (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Hispanic or Latino"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:55.5143em; left:22.3817em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_28" style="word-spacing:0.0024em;">Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:56.4693em; left:22.3817em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_34" style="word-spacing:-0.0031em;">Multi-ethnic minority ownership (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Multi-ethnic minority ownership"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:57.4309em; left:22.3817em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:-0.001em;">Multi-ethnic ownership (50% Minority – 50% Non-Minority) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Multi-ethnic ownership"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:58.3909em; left:22.4067em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_37" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Decline to state &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Decline to state"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:57.4309em; left:5.84em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_38" style="word-spacing:-0.002em;">Caucasian / White (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Caucasian / White"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stl_01" style="top:58.3909em; left:5.84em;">
                        <span class="stl_07 stl_08 stl_28" style="word-spacing:0.0025em;">Filipino (&gt; 50%) &nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="input checkbox" name="ethnicity"
                               value="Filipino"
                               style="left: -1.28em;top: 0.07em;"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Section 8 Ends-->
```

This is JavaScript code for converting webform to PDF and sending to the designated email after user filled in data:

```
function exportPdf() {
        return new Promise((resolve) =>{
            loadData.then(() =>{
                const element = document.querySelector('.container');
                const pdfOptions = {
                    pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all', after: '.stl_02' },
                    margin: 0, 
                    filename: 'output.pdf',
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                    html2canvas: { scale: 2 }, 
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
                };
                html2pdf().from(element).set(pdfOptions).output().then(binaryString =>{
                    
                    const binaryArray = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
                        binaryArray[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    
                    const blob = new Blob([binaryArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    
                    const pdfFile = new File([blob], 'output.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    resolve(pdfFile)
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

My problem:
The workflow appears to be functioning correctly: the user enters data and clicks a button labeled 'Save and Send.' The web form is then generated in PDF format and sent as an attachment to the designated email. However, upon opening the attachment in the email, sections 8 and 9 in the PDF appear as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTBFb.png)

The square checkboxes have transformed into round radio buttons. Although I understand that radio buttons are what I used in HTML, I still want the document to display square boxes, as shown on the website.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance on these matters. Thank you!

To supplement my question, this is the sendEmail function in the related controller class:

```
@PostMapping("/send-email")
    public AjaxResult sendEmail(@RequestBody List<String> filenames) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        SecurityUser securityUser = (SecurityUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("vendorForm.pdf");
        for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(uploadPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + File.separator + filenames.get(i));
            String filename = "";
            if (i < names.size()){
                filename = names.get(i);
            }else {
                filename = filenames.get(i);
            }
            fileMap.put(filename, file);
        }
        emailService.send(fileMap, securityUser.getUser().getEmail());
        return AjaxResult.ok();
    }
```